# filtering out strings in a list Python

Tags: python

I'm totally new to Python and I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I want to remove all Strings.

```
def filter_list(l):
for f in l:
    if isinstance(f, str):
        l.remove(f)
return l

print(filter_list([1,2,'a','b']))
```

The output I get is:

[1,2,'b']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error came from removing items from `list` in iteration and at last, you don't check the last item *(for more details read this : [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating))* For this approach remove items with `list comprehension`.

```
def filter_list(l):
    return [f for f in l if not isinstance(f, str)]

print(filter_list([1,2,'a','b'])) 
# [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Often when we need to filter a sublist from a list given a condition, you'll see this sort of syntax (i.e. list comprehension) quite commonly, which serves to do the exact same thing. It's up to you which style you prefer:

```py
a = [1,2,'a','b']
b = [x for x in a if not isinstance(x, str)]
print(b)  # [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

so you can do something like

```py
def filter_list(l)
for f in l:
  if type(f) == str:
    l.remove(f)
return l
```